# Flexbox justify-content: space-around; Not Working..?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create some blog site layout, but the problem here is I can't make space between content and sidebar. I applied `flexbox`, but `justify-content` is not working. I don't know why, I'm using this latest chrome browser.

I attached the following code I am facing `justify-content` issue. Please help me out this what I am missing here.

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* .homepage {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  } */

  .top-poster {
      background-color: yellow;
      color: red;
  }

  .header {
      background-color: steelblue;
      color: snow;
  }

  .top-navigation {
      background-color: black;
      color: whitesmoke;
  }

  .main-content {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      /* align-content: space-around; */
      /* margin: 20px; */
      /* padding: 20px; */
  }

  .content {
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 20px;
      /* order: 2; */
  }

  .right-sidebar {
      background-color: khaki;
      border: 2px solid red;
      /* order: 1; */
  }

  .fakeimg {
      background-color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog Codings</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        <div class="top-poster">your add will show here</div>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Blog Codings</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="top-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Learn</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Dummy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text..</p>
                <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                <br>
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text..</p>
                <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-sidebar">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
                <h3>More Text</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>@Copywrite to BlogCodings.com</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` will not add margin in between elements automatically. You need to assign the margin between the elements manually. Here's an example:

```css
.main-content > *:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* .homepage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
} */

.top-poster {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}

.header {
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: snow;
}

.top-navigation {
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.main-content {
    display: flex;
}

.content {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
    /* order: 2; */
}

.right-sidebar {
    background-color: khaki;
    border: 2px solid red;
    /* order: 1; */
}

.fakeimg {
    background-color: gray;
}

.main-content > *:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog Codings</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        <div class="top-poster">your add will show here</div>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Blog Codings</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="top-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Learn</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Dummy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text..</p>
                <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                <br>
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text..</p>
                <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-sidebar">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
                <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
                <h3>More Text</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
                <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>@Copywrite to BlogCodings.com</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox `justify-content` property used to arrange child items horizontally. But for controlling the flow of child elements horizontally you have to set `flex-basis` or `width` on child items, then after you control the horizontal flow and used `justify-content` property. As I saw your CSS, you didn't set `width` or `flex-basis` property on your child items, hence `justify-content` didn't work. Add `width` according to your requirement and use `justify-content: flex-start/flex-end/center/space-around/space-between`.

```
.content {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
    width:600px;
    /* order: 2; */
}

.right-sidebar {
    background-color: khaki;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width:200px;
    /* order: 1; */
}
```